# UITableView Reloading Issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am in very complex issue of reloading UITableView!

I've a `UITableView` in which I am continuously (near by 10seconds), retrieving data from a server and showing that data in my `UITableView` that contains custom cells. The issue is that, when user (thats me) is scrolling through the `UITableView` it will crash due to an `indexOutOfBound` error as I am fetching data from the server the `NSMutableArray` will clear and fill again with data.

I also tried with a `BOOL` variable setting `YES` or `NO` in `scrolling delegates`. In this case if I scroll `UITableView` it will remove the cell of scroll direction, after 10 seconds it will show all cells with data.

But what I want is that, if user scrolls `UITableView` none of the created cell should hide! `scrollEnabled` is not a solution for that.

Please help me out!

Thanks :)

Comment: I suspect what's happening is that you're updating your table view while scrolling out of bounds at the same time.  You need to either *lock* the table view updating while scrolling (so you can't go out of bounds) or you need to only allow scrolling to the maximum number of entries in your table at the time of your last update (without removing any cells or entries before the scrolling is done).  Either way, this kind of updating is really tricky and it sounds like a fun problem you get to solve.

Comment: Make sure the number of section and number of rows changed only after all data is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a thread unsafe code issue. data source being modified while it is being actively used.

one safe solution would be to feed all data after parsing to some DB (sqlite/Coredata) and reload the table datasource from db and call reloadData for table. this way at the time when you were using the datasource array - it wont be empty.

best of luck

Comment: I ran into this problem just the other day, and yes, the best way to go about this is to not update the actual data source while retrieving from a server.  Make a separate data source, store the server values in it, and then assign the separate data source to your table's data source.  The operation should be as close to atomic as possible.

Comment: The solution you provided was came into my mind! but it can be advisable in case I will not fetching data continuously!:)

Answer (score 0):

if indexOutOfBound means you must check numberofrow that you specified is more than the our array receive in the cell forrowatindex. so check that.